# Is there any reactive DynamoDB library available for node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, reactive-programming

I have a use case:

My DynamoDB table does have 500,000 records. Now I want to query and get the all records via business-Api and want them to throw to UI layer(for example reactJs UI app). 
Here, the problem is, if I will normally query then It will block the call until all the 500,000 records it fetches in-memory in API and also it will take hell lot of time and User has to wait till that time.

Hence, I am looking for  some reactive pattern so once query happens to Dynamo table, It should start streaming the records back to API.

I searched over internet. However, couldn't get the proper resource. Can someone guide what should I use here?

Comment: Why are you thinking of showing 500k records in your UI? Shouldn't you show fewer records, perhaps driven by a search query or filter that the user supplies? If you genuinely want the option to show 500k then you should use some kind of pagination control so that when you click Next/Previous it will go to the server and request the next paginated list of records from DynamoDB. Basically you would show one page at a time, where a 'page' could be anything from 50 to 1000 records. But I cannot imagine a user paging through 500k records.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you're looking for here is paging. Keep in mind that paging doesn't have to be classic pages in the UI, it can be continuous scrolling, or even managed completely in your JavaScript code (if you really want to load all 500K in memory). DynamoDB includes paging natively. Keep in mind that the paging in DynamoDB is a little strange in that you can get pages of varying sizes (including empty pages), even if you specify the max records.